# Why do I get a 404 when I include wp-blog-header.php in a page that is the target of a POST action?

Tags: wordpress, http-post

I have a form in a Wordpress blog that uses a PHP file as the action for a POST when the form is submitted.  The PHP file is outside the normal WP context, but I want to be able to read some custom fields from my WP database, so I have included wp-blog-header.php in this file as explained [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).  However, as soon as I include the file, the POST fails with a 404.  If I remove the include it works fine.  Does WP have some sort of security mechanism that prevents wp-blog-header.php from being loaded on a POST?  Is there some way to get around this?

The main goal is to pull the value from an Advanced Custom Fields field on a particular page in my WP site.  If there is a good way to do this without including wp-blog-header.php I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form is posting a field with a parameter of `name`, a 404 will result.

Comment: Yes, this was my problem.  Thanks!  Care to give a bit more explanation for why this happens?

Comment: Sorry I saw this so late, I haven't looked into it in over a year but it has something to do with the routing/permalink rewriting that Wordpress does.

Comment: This answer was a lifesaver for me today... Thanks so much!!!